# Pop up box when hover over div

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using asp.net in VS 2013.

I want to display a pop up window when a user hovers over a div.  I have 3 divs on the page and they are each a square of approx. 50x50.  When the user brings their mouse over each one I want a different pop up box to appear.

I have been playing about with the hovermenuextender to achieve this but Im not getting anywhere as it needs a control as its target.  IS there anyway to achieve this with an Ajax control?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a pop-up div on mouse over and stay when click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064226/how-to-create-a-pop-up-div-on-mouse-over-and-stay-when-click)

Comment: your solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064226/how-to-create-a-pop-up-div-on-mouse-over-and-stay-when-click

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

step 1: Keep the three pop ups with different ids in your html with style = "display:none;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;". and a classname popup.

e.g.

```
<div class="popup" id="1" style = "display:none;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;"></div>
```

step 2: Give classname (respective ids of hidden divs)  to your divs on which user will hover and a parent attribute to your divs.

e.g.

```
<div class="showdiv" parent="1"></div>
```

step 3: now write following code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

           $('.showdiv').mouseover(function() {

              $(".popup").hide();
              $("'#"+$(this).attr('parent')+"'").show();                       

           });     

  });

    try prop if attr doen't work.
```